Cross tenant data copy using adf and storage account is not working
I am trying to copy  a csv file using an ADF copy activity from tenant A to a storage account in tenant B . I have done the following  configs

Created a cross tenant Service Principal
This service principal has storage blob data contributor access
Created a managed private end point from the ADF to the storage account
Approved this Private end point in storage blob
ADF uses a IR that has managed virtual network enabled

The copy activity fails with the  error below
ErrorCode=AdlsGen2ForbiddenError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 failed for forbidden: Storage operation 'CreateFile' on container 'testContainer' and path 'test/market/testfile.csv' get failed with 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden''. Possible root causes: (1). It's possible because the service principal or managed identity don't have enough permission to access the data. (2). If you are using private endpoint to connect the Azure Storage, it's possible because private endpint didn't be created and configured correctly, please follow https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private to create it again. (3). If you are not using private endpoint to connect the Azure Storage, it's possible because some IP address ranges of Azure Data Factory are not allowed by your Azure Storage firewall settings, you are suggested to create private endpoint to connect your Azure Storage.. Account: 'StorageAccounttest'. FileSystem: 'testContainer'. Path: 'test/market/testfile.csv'. ErrorCode: 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch'. Message: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.'. RequestId: 'abcedgxxxxxxxx'. TimeStamp: 'Thu, 05 Dec 2024 14:58:05 GMT'..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden',Source=,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.Models.ErrorSchemaException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
I am not sure if there is anything that I am missing

Ensure the Service Principal in tenant B has Storage Blob Data Contributor role assigned at the correct scope

The Service Principal  has all needed permissions


ADLS Gen2 failed for forbidden: Storage operation 'CreateFile' on container 'testContainer' and path 'test/market/testfile.csv' get failed with 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden''

The error you're getting indicates that there might be permission or configuration issues in your Azure Data Factory (ADF) setup where you are coping CSV file from tenant A to tenant B
Ensure the Service Principal has "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role assigned on the scope of Storage account or particular container and it does not in ACL (Access control lists) where it is restricting access to container. also check the role is applied in correct tenant where storage account lies.

Confirm that the Storage Account firewall allows traffic from your ADF's Managed Private Endpoint. Ensure that there are no restrictive NSG rules preventing communication between the ADF and the storage account.
Also make sure you configure API permissions to app while app registration, app must own a permission to communicate with a data lake service.

To give permission Go to your app >> Settings >> API permission >> Add Permissions >>Azure Data Lake >> Delegated permissions >> user_impersonation >> Add permission.


Your app has now a full access to the Azure Data Lake service, and you can use this service principal to authenticate with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.
